# How to use C# Dependency injection

Tags: c#

Sorry for the beginner question.

I wanted to learn Dependency Injection, so I tried to imitate a simple sample.

- Products　ConsoleApp
- Version　.Net6

Below, there are two files: Program.cs and Application.cs.

*Program.cs*

```
using DependencyInjectionDemo.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
IHost _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices(
    services => {
         services.AddSingleton<IApplication, Application>();
    })
    .Build();

var app = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IApplication>();
app.TestRun();
```

*Application.cs*

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DependencyInjectionDemo.Services
{
    internal interface IApplication
    {
        void TestRun();
    }

    internal class Application : IApplication
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Application> _logger;

        public Application(ILogger<Application> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


        public void TestRun()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Logging form the Application classssssssssssss!");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World form the Application class!");
        }
    }
}
```

I can call TestRun of the Application class from Program.cs without any problems, but for example, how can I create a new Test class and call TestRun of the Application class from there?

*Test.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DependencyInjectionDemo
{
    internal class Test
    {
        public void CallTestRun()
        {
            // How can I call TestRun in Application class?
        }
    }
}
```

Modified version

*Test.cs*

```
namespace DependencyInjectionDemo.Services
{
    internal interface ITest
    {
        void CallTestRun();
    }

    internal class Test : ITest
    {
        private IApplication _app;

        public Test(IApplication app)
        {
            _app = app;
        }

        public void CallTestRun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World form the Test class!");
            _app.TestRun();
        }
    }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

IHost _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices(
    services => {
        services.AddSingleton<IApplication, Application>();
        services.AddSingleton<ITest, Test>();
    })
    .Build();

var app = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IApplication>();
app.TestRun();

var test = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<ITest>();
test.CallTestRun();
```

[image]

I'm concerned that the order in which the logs are output is incorrect...

Comment: You need to register the relevant classes and create a services provider or a host.  Then you can use that to create an Application class instance which will have the correct injections.    There's plenty of example available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take a step back and go over the basics of what dependency injection is, without the automatic registration done in .NET

Assume a file Program.cs where the main thread begins its course.
Say that you have two seperate classes:

```
class App {

  private Helper helper;

  public App(Helper _helper){
    helper = _helper;
  }

  public int GetZero(){
    return helper.GetZero();
  }

}

class Helper {
  public Helper(){

  }

  public int GetZero(){
   return 0;
  }

}
```

We can now see that App.cs "depends" on the Helper.cs class.
This means that in our Program.cs, we would have to create a new instance of both classes and "inject" the Helper class into the App class:

*In program.cs*

```
.....code.....
Helper helper = new Helper();
App app = new App(helper);
app.GetZero();
..............
```

We must make sure that the helper object is created before the app object, as app is *dependent* on helper and is practically useless without it.

In .NET, this is somewhat automatically handled by the DI container. Typically, it is done within the ConfigureServices method. However, when registering services, you must keep a note to register the dependencies first and then do the dependent services afterwards.

In your case, this would be something of the sort:

```
....
namespace DependencyInjectionDemo
{
    internal class Test
    {
        private Application app;
        public Test(Application _app) {
           app = _app;
        }

        public void CallTestRun()
        {
           app.TestRun();
        }
    }
}
...
```

In *Program.cs*

```
using DependencyInjectionDemo.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
IHost _host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices(
    services => {
         services.AddSingleton<IApplication, Application>();
         services.AddSingleton<ITest, Test>();
    })
    .Build();

var app = _host.Services.GetRequiredService<IApplication>();
app.TestRun();
```

I have omitted the creation of an Interface for your Test class service, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

I modified the code based on your advice.

By defining ITest, the interface of the Test class, and adding that interface to the service, we were able to call TestRun of the Application class from CallTestRun of the Test class.

What I don't quite understand yet is is adding services only done in one place throughout the program? (services.AddSingleton<ITest, Test>(); part)

Comment: @BTOM The classes you register in program.cs are usually considered "services" that would last the entire lifetime of the application. Hence, why you also register them as singletons, as there is only one object alive of that kind and must be passed around in order to be used in different contexts. 
I would suggest reading up on the different types of object lifetimes in .NET
[here](https://medium.com/@csharpian/exploring-dependency-lifecycles-singleton-vs-transient-vs-scoped-f07592ab9953)

Answer (score 2):

In C# console app, first you need to install the package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Then build your dependency provider object like the following code:

```cs
var serviceCollection = new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IInnerService, InnerService>();//Register dependencies
                                                              //Register dependencies for Foo service that contains 'InnerService'
serviceCollection.AddTransient<IFooService, FooService>();
serviceCollection.AddLogging(); //add logging dependency


IServiceProvider provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(); //Build your DI dependency injection provider

var serv2 = provider.GetService<IFooService>();

serv2.DoThing(9);
serv2.InnerService.DoSomeRealWork();

public interface IFooService
{
    void DoThing(int number);

    IInnerService InnerService { get; set; }
}

public interface IInnerService
{
    void DoSomeRealWork();


}

public class InnerService : IInnerService
{
    private readonly IFooService _fooService;
    public InnerService()
    {
    }

    public void DoSomeRealWork()
    {
    }
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private readonly IInnerService _barServ;
    private readonly ILogger<IInnerService> _logger;
    public FooService(IInnerService barServ, ILogger<IInnerService> logger)
    {
        _barServ = barServ;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoThing(int number)
    {
        _barServ.DoSomeRealWork();
    }

    public IInnerService InnerService
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I'm confused because there are various ways to create a dependency provider object.

The code I referenced uses IHost's CreateDefaultBuilder, but I use the BuildServiceProvider you taught me.

Which one is commonly used?

Comment: I also tried the code you provided.

I think I got a bit of an idea by looking at the FooService constructor.
I understand that the class you want to use is injected via the constructor in the provider.GetService<IFooService>(); part.

However, you won't be able to master it unless you try it a few times and get used to it, so it seems like I need practice.